# Microsoft Graph User Profiles and Power BI

Tags: graph, permissions, powerbi

I'm trying to create a dashboard to show how many profiles in Delve have been completed by our user base.  It looks like Graph is the way to go, and using OData, I've successfully connected to Users.  My issue is that the related lists are showing up blank when I drill into them, even though there are entries.

My assumption is that I don't have necessary permissions, and will need Users.Read.All to get to this data.

Could someone point me to how this is done, and whether I'm actually looking at the right cause?

Thanks in advance,
Darren